# Identify changes made by eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I am using Resource Change Listener to track the changes done to my project. Out of these changes i want know if the change was done via Eclipse menu or some other eclipse plugin or if it was typed in by user. Please suggest a way to achieve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure whether there is a direct API to to that, because the interface [`IResourceDelta`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fcore%2Fresources%2FIResourceChangeListener.html) that it mainly implements does not have a method on who modified the resource.

You can track most the changes mainly on the resource it modified, but 'who' modified it is an unanswered question for me too. I found this resource useful in this regards,
http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Resource-deltas/resource-deltas.html